# firestore remove a data from array field

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using this function on a button.
And one of id string added to "friends" array but one if id doesnt remove from array field in documention. I dont know why "arrayRemove" code doesn work.

```
  Future<void> acceptFriendRequest(String id) async {
    try {
      
      CollectionReference user = FirebaseCollectionsEnum.user.col;
      user.doc(id).update({
        "friends": FieldValue.arrayUnion([box.read("userUID")])
      });
      user.doc(box.read("userUID")).update({
        "friendRequest": FieldValue.arrayRemove([id])
      });
    } catch (e) {
      errorSnackbar(
          "FirebaseFireStoreController, acceptFriendRequest ERROR:", "$e");
    }
  }
```

EDİT:
firestore
[image]

EDIT2:
when i accept to another user's request. that user's id will be in current user's "friends" array, but wont remove from current user's "friendRequest" array.
[image]

here changes in firebase firestore
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: I didnt get anything

Comment: What does `box.read("userUID")` return? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo box.read("userUID") is returning current user's firebaseID.

Comment: Which is? Show that to us.

Comment: Have you tried `FieldValue.arrayRemove([box.read("userUID")]]`?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, no change..